How to appropriately call init function of external JS on page ready when using NextJS and Redux
I am maintaining a NextJS and Redux based website hosted by Vercel.
Newly added feature requires a big piece of JavaScript, so I wrote it in a separated file and included it using  tag in the feature component.
Due to the usage of redux I cannot use an initialiser in the script itself, but rather call it whenever the page is ready.
Although my IDE marks an error on 'SomeFeature.init()' due to the internally unknown function call, the feature works perfectly fine on my dev environment as the function is set by the time when the page is ready.
However, the problem appears when building:
Failed to compile. Type error: Cannot find name 'SomeFeature'.

The code looks something like:
"use client"

import Script from 'next/script';

...

export default () => {
  return (
    <>
        <div>....</div>
        <Script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/SomeFeature.js" onReady={() => { SomeFeature.init() }} />
    </>
  )
}

What is the normal approach to initialising an external JS code on pageReady, with the setup described above? Unfortunately I didn't find any viable resource yet.

I ended up creating a global.d.ts file in the root folder with the following code:
export {};

declare global {
  interface Window {
    SomeFeature: {
      initialize: () => void;
    };
  }
}

I don't know if this is the best approach, but it solves the build-time problem.
